# How to hide a keyboard bar with buttons Previous and Next on UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, keyboard

1). How to hide a keyboard bar with buttons Previous and Next on UIWebView? The two buttons are inactive and it's better to hide them. How to do this?

[image]

2). How to get height of this bar?

Thanks a lot for the help!

**If you hit this problem**, make sure to head over to https://bugreport.apple.com and duplicate rdar://9844216

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIWebView Keyboard - Getting rid of the “Previous/Next/Done” bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105858/uiwebview-keyboard-getting-rid-of-the-previous-next-done-bar). You might be out of luck here...

Comment: Yes. But how to get height of hidden bar? Because keyboard's height is returned with invisible bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 44px for iPad 3. I think, it's the same for other devices.